# Angular material datepicker has weird styling

Tags: angular, angular-material, styling

I was trying to make a good looking datepicker, something like in the material datepicker [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

Datepicker I want

[image]

But I ended up with a weird looking datepicker that I can write text over and has awful styling, can anyone help with this?

My datepicker

[image]

Edit: this warning might be part of the problem?
Warning: (C://path..)\node_modules\ngx-material-timepicker_*ivy_ngcc*_\fesm2015\ngx-material-timepicker.js depends on 'luxon'. CommonJS or AMD
dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

new-reservation.component.html

```
<h3>Create reservation here</h3>
<form [formGroup]="reservationForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <div>
      <input matInput>
      <ngx-timepicker-field [defaultTime]="'12:00 am'" formControlName="beginTime"></ngx-timepicker-field>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
  <br/>
  <mat-form-field>
    <div>
      <input matInput formControlName="endTime">
      <ngx-timepicker-field [defaultTime]="'12:00 am'" formControlName="endTime"></ngx-timepicker-field>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Choose date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" min="{{ currentDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" formControlName="date">
    <mat-hint>DD MM YYYY</mat-hint>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker startView="year"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
  <br/><br/>
  <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

new-reservation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { NewReservationService } from './new-reservation.service';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-reservation',
  templateUrl: './new-reservation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-reservation.component.scss'],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class NewReservationComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private newReservationService: NewReservationService) { }

  currentDate: any = new Date();

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  reservationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    beginTime: '',
    endTime: '',
    date: '',
    checkedin: false,
    canceled: false
  });
  onFormSubmit() {
    this.newReservationService.saveStudent(this.reservationForm.value);
    this.reservationForm.reset();
  }

}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewReservationService {
  saveStudent(reservation) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(reservation));
  }
}
```

app-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from "./register/register.component";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {RegisterService} from "./register/register.service";
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { MainHeaderComponent } from './main-header/main-header.component';
import { CurrentReservationsComponent } from './reservations/current-reservations/current-reservations.component';
import { CheckInComponent } from './reservations/check-in/check-in.component';
import { NewReservationComponent } from './reservations/new-reservation/new-reservation.component';
import { ReservationsComponent } from './reservations/reservations.component';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from "@angular/material/slide-toggle";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NgxMaterialTimepickerModule} from "ngx-material-timepicker";
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    MainHeaderComponent,
    CurrentReservationsComponent,
    CheckInComponent,
    NewReservationComponent,
    ReservationsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    NgxMaterialTimepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    RegisterService, 
    MatDatepickerModule
     
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  schemas: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: expect date picker rest of two control working fine? I mean ngx-timepicker-field working finr and which version you are using for angular material and ngx-timepicker-field.

Comment: @JayPatel I am using 
"ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3", 
"@angular/material": "^13.3.9"

Comment: looks everything up to date, is there any error in console? if any please add that error in question

Comment: @JayPatel I did have a warning, which I just added to the post, but I'm not sure if that's part of the problem

Comment: comment out code for ngx-timepicker-field and keep only date picker control and check in browser what you are getting there.

Comment: @JayPatel I still have the same styling for the datepicker when I comment out the ngx-timepicker-field or the entire mat-form-field that the timepickers are in

Comment: are you applying any custom style on date picker?

Comment: @JayPatel yes, I have appearance = "standard", I also tried appearance = "fill"
but it doesn't really seem to do much except change the box that the date is filled in for